# CGPDF drawPDFPage with rotation support

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation, core-graphics, cgpdf

I'm saving a PDF file with CGPDF under iOS 10. For this I load an existing PDF page, and write it to a new file with a context. While doing so, the rotation information gets lost and the resulting PDF file has all pages re-arragend at 0°.

```
let writeContext: CGContext = CGContext(finalPDFURL, mediaBox: nil, nil)!

// Loop through all pages
let page: CGPDFPage = ...
var mediaBox = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
writeContext.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
writeContext.drawPDFPage(page)
writeContext.endPage()
// Loop finished

writeContext.closePDF()
```

Then I came up with this code, which handles rotation just fine, but seems to draw the content with a slight offset. Using it with a PDF which has text or anything else close to the margins, results in cut-off content. Tried later also setting x, y, etc. on the pageInfo dict but I guess I misunderstood something here, see 2nd question below.

```
let page: CGPDFPage = ...

// Set the rotation
var pageDict = [String: Int32]()
pageDict["Rotate"] = CGFloat.init(page.rotationAngle)

writeContext.beginPDFPage(pageDict as CFDictionary?)
writeContext.drawPDFPage(page)
writeContext.endPDFPage()
```

So my questions,

1) How to use the first approach but with rotation support? Or the second one, but without cropping of content?

2) Where would I find a complete listing of all available pageInfo key-value pairs for this method? https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456578-beginpdfpage

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, but hope following answer will be useful for someone in the future. It will preserve the rotation information of the original PDF page

> 1. How to use the first approach but with rotation support?

```
let writeContext: CGContext = CGContext(finalPDFURL, mediaBox: nil, nil)!

// Loop through all pages
let page: CGPDFPage = ...
var mediaBox = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
writeContext.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)

let m = page.getDrawingTransform(.mediaBox, rect: mediaBox, rotate: 0, preserveAspectRatio: true)

// Following 3 lines makes the rotations so that the page look in the right direction
writeContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: mediaBox.size.height)
writeContext.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
writeContext.concatenate(m)

writeContext.drawPDFPage(page)
writeContext.endPage()
// Loop finished

writeContext.closePDF()
```

Answer (score -1):

I got feedback from a fellow iOS coder who suggested following principle:

These three steps should allow you to recreate the original page in the destination, while maintaining the page rotation field: (1) set the source page rotation in the destination page via the page dictionary, (2) set that rotation (or possibly the rotation * -1?) in the CGContext you’re drawing into, and finally (3) explicitly set the media box in the destination to be identical to the source (no rotation).

Comment: As stated I only got feedback, no code examples, I still think these pointers might be of help to someone someday, that's why I added them.
In the meantime I switched to Apple's updated PDFKit which is much more pleasant to work with